# Socket.listen not reusing new connections

Tags: python, sockets

I am writing a simple socket api with client/server model. I was just testing with socket.listen backlog parameter to see if it actually drops new connections, but for some reason it is not working as expected,below is my code.

```
import socket
import sys
from threading import Thread

HOST = ('localhost', 55555)
try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind(HOST)
    print('Bind successful')
except socket.error as e:
    print('Error ocurred ')

print('Listening for connections')
sock.listen(1)


def client_conn(conn):
    while True:
        # waiting for data to be received
        data_recv = conn.recv(1024)
        if not data_recv:
            print('No data recieved from the client')
            conn.close()
            break
        reply = 'Okay ' + data_recv.decode()
        conn.send(reply.encode('utf-8'))


while True:
    # waiting for connections
    conn, client = sock.accept()
    print('Recieved connection from {}:{}'.format(client[0], client[1]))
    conn.send(b'Hiii')
    Thread(target=client_conn, args=(conn, )).start()

sock.close()
```

### Output

**Server.py**

```
$ python3.6 /Programs/sockets/server.py

Bind successful
Listening for connections
Recieved connection from 127.0.0.1:33402
Recieved connection from 127.0.0.1:33408
Recieved connection from 127.0.0.1:33414
```

As you can see I connected from three clients and all seem to get connected and communicate with server just fine.

Can anyone please explain this ?

Comment: What's the exact question? You say it's not working at the top and then you say it's working at the bottom? Are you sure that the clients are sending data?

Comment: If you look at the code sock.listen(1), so only one client should be able to connect at one time, however i have 3 simultaneous connections at the same time sending data, so how other 2 are able to connect despite socket.listen(1) ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.listen) of `socket.listen`:

> socket.listen(backlog)
>   Listen for connections made to the socket.
>   The `backlog` argument specifies the maximum number of queued
>   connections and should be at least 0; the maximum value is
>   system-dependent (usually 5), the minimum value is forced to 0.

The `backlog` argument of `socket.listen(backlog)` doesn't dictate the number of connections that the server can maintain but rather how many incoming connections can be **queued** and handled one after the other.

So in your case of `server.listen(1)`, the server can have many open connections but it can only handle two incoming connections being made to it at a particular moment i.e. while it handles the first connection (by allocating it resources etc.) the second connection is kept waiting in a queue. If there's a third incoming connection at the same moment as well, it will be dropped.

**Note**:
There's a difference between `open` connections and `incoming` connections. Your server can maintain many simultaneous open connections while it can handle only few simultaneous incoming connections. In your case those 3 connections are `open`.

Comment: Here is the snippet from Python3.6 documentations

_**socket.listen([backlog])
Enable a server to accept connections. If backlog is specified, it must be at least 0 (if it is lower, it is set to 0); it specifies the number of unaccepted connections that the system will allow before refusing new connections. If not specified, a default reasonable value is chosen.**_

Comment: Also i just tested by creating 4 connections at the same time and still none got refused/dropped.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding. A server takes a small amount of time to handle an **incoming & unaccepted** connection because it needs to allocate some resources etc. Before it processes one incoming connection, if another connection is made to the server, then this connection is kept in a queue. `backlog` determines how big the queue is. Once an incoming connection is **accepted** then it is kept open and you can do your business logic. The server can keep 65536 connections open at anytime. So in your case the server has 4 simultaneous open connections.